# Hardhat metamask error - "Trying to send a raw transaction with an invalid chainId. The expected chainId is 31337"

Tags: reactjs, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm working with hardhat and ethers js. It's working fine when executing reading function but I'm getting this error while using writing function--

> MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32602,"message":"Trying to send a raw transaction with an invalid chainId. The expected chainId is 31337","data":{"message":"Trying to send a raw transaction with an invalid chainId. The expected chainId is 31337"}}}}'

here's my code--

App.js

```
import './App.css'
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {

 const [participantName, setParticipantName] = useState()
 const [candidatesArray, setCandidatesArray] = useState([])

 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
 const signer = provider.getSigner();
 const contractAddress = ""

 const abi = []

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)

async function Connect() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    try {
      await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
      console.log('connected')
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  } 
}

async function Participate() {
  try {
    await contract.participate(participantName);
    console.log(participantName + " added successfully")
  
  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
  }
}

async function noOfCandidates() {
  const noCand = await contract.noOfCandidates();
  console.log(noCand.toString())
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Election Poll</h1>
    <button onClick={Connect}>Connect</button>
    <div className="participate">
      <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setParticipantName(e.target.value)}}/>
      <button onClick={Participate}>Participate</button>
    </div>
    <div className="noOfCand">
      <button onClick={noOfCandidates}>Number of candidates running</button>
    </div>
    <div className="candArray">
      <h4>{candidatesArray}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}

export default App
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
const Election = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Election");
const election = await Election.deploy();

await election.deployed();

console.log("Election deployed to:", election.address);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.8",
  };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Change the chainId within your metamask configuration to 31337 for your local network (e.g. http://localhost:8545)

[image: metamaskNetworkConfig]

Alternatively manually set the chainId within your hardhat config:

```js
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      url: process.env.RPC_URL,
      chainId: 1337,
    }
 }
```